# Is it possible to use two record helpers for the string type?

Tags: delphi, class-helpers

I created this helper in order to add some more functions to the `string` type:

```
type
  AStringHelper = record helper for string
    function Invert: string; overload;
    function InvertMe: string; overload;
  end;
```

But when I use it in my code, the `TStringHelper` in `System.StrUtils` "gets out" and I can't use it's functions.

Is it possible to both of them to coexist?

Comment: FWIW, Reverse is a more commonly used name for what I think your function does.

Comment: I used to use Reverse too...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At most one helper can active at any one point in your code. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers) says this:

> You can define and associate multiple helpers with a single
>   type. However, only zero or one helper applies in any
>   specific location in source code. The helper defined in the
>   nearest scope will apply. Class or record helper scope is
>   determined in the normal Delphi fashion (for example, right
>   to left in the unit's uses clause).

Since record helpers do not support inheritance, there's no way to have both the standard helper's and your helper's functionality active at the same time, other than re-implementing the standard helper's functionality.

Comment: Indeed, reimplementing would be easiest, simply by using the TStringHelper functions to implement the reimplementation, IOW using aggregation instead of inheritance.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: What do you meant re-implementing?  Can you give an example?

Comment: Simply write a new string helper and use the existing string helper to implement it. Problem is that a helper can not have its own instance variables, though.

Comment: Five years later and it's still not possible to have custom StringHelper functions additionally to the existing ones (without copying/modifying the original unit or odd workarounds like the other answers here)? This is so frustrating. Any idea why Embarcadero still doesn't allow record helper inheritance?

Answer (score 7):

Try to create your own class and helper

```
TMyString = type string;
TMyStringHelper = record helper for TMyString 
  function Invert: TMyString; 
  function ToString: string;
end;
```

Use TMyString instead of String.

To use standard String helpers wrap TMyString variable with String() or use ToString method.

```
var
  S1: TMyString;
  S2: String;
begin
  S1 := ' 123456 ';
  S1.Invert;
  S2 := String(S1).Trim;
  S2 := S1.ToString.Trim;
end;
```

Comment: I actually tried this out and it is working perfectly. The only thing you might have to do is put a string into your TMyString value before you can  use your TMyString record hleper

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use the "Ancestor list" option offered by helpers

Syntaxis:

```
type
identifierName = class|record helper [(ancestor list)] for TypeIdentifierName
  memberList
end;
```

And use like this:

```
Unit1:   
THelperBase = Class helper for TMyClass
Public
  Function SayHello;
end;

Unit2:
Uses Unit1;
THelperChild = Class helper (THelperBase) for TMyClass
Public
  Function SayGoodBye;
end;
```

And finally, in your code:

```
Uses Unit2;   

Var MyClass: TMyclass;   

MyClass:= TMyclass.Create;
MyClass.SayHello; //valid
MyClass.SayGoodBye; //valid
```

Comment: "The ancestor list is optional. It can be specified only for class helper." So this seems to be a solution for class helpers, but not for record helpers :-(

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution to this could be:

```
type
  TStr = record
  private
    FStr:string;
  public
    function Invert: string; overload;
    function InvertMe: string; overload;
  end;
```

By using type casting you can access the functions on `TStr` on a ordinary `string` variable:

```
var
  s1,s2:string;
begin
  s1:='123456';
  s2:=TStr(s1).invert;
end;
```

But of course, then we can ask: Why not just write an ordinary function? :-)

Anyway, I like this `class` / `object` / `record` method syntax better than traditional function/procedure.

Comment: Because the dudes think that this object method ways are better and we should not use them mixed with directly function calls. :-/